# Compiling with g++, can't change library path

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I can't seem to get this working. I have a c++ script that I haven't written myself, that I need to compile with g++. The start of the script looks like this:

```
#include "x.hh"
#include "y.hh"

#include <iostream>
...
```

I understand that when using include with quotation marks, that means there are external libraries that have to be included when doing the compiling. The header files, x.hh and y.hh, as well as the files x.cc and y.cc (which I guess are the libraries) plus the main script are all in the same folder. I've tried to compile them with:

```
g++ Documents/Cpp/script.cc -o script -L Documents/Cpp -lx -ly
```

This returns the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld cannot find -lx
/usr/bin/ld cannot find -ly
collect2 returned 1 exit status
```

The search path isn't the same as I specified. Even if I write

```
g++ Documents/Cpp/script.cc -o script -L sdfsdf/sdfsd-lx -ly
```

It still looks in /usr/bin/ld folder. No matter what I write in -L I can't get it to work. How?

Comment: `x.hh` is a *header file*. A library usually would be called `libx.so` under Linux.

Comment: Quotation marks in a `#include` have nothing to do with linking. Try linking without `-lx -ly`, those libraries don't seem to exist.

Comment: If i remove the -lx and -ly i get a lot of error messages looking like: script.cc:(.text+0x26d) undefined reference to 'x::x()' script.cc:(.text+0x26d) undefined reference to 'y::y()'

Answer (score 0):

Compile all .cc files, they are all required to build the program.

```
g++ Documents/Cpp/*.cc sdfsdf/*.cc -o script
```

(Assuming `sdfsdf` is the path to x.cc and y.cc)

Comment: @user2812393 And read again a tutorial on compiling C++ code, and something about what are libraries ;)